# How to upgrade legacy aspx to html based website or go with asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

a quick background. I have my website done using asp.net (webforms I believe) and it has default.aspx with sitemaster page (not mobile friendly).  I have added html pages with separate css as well. (a) Except for main page default.aspx, all other pages are in html (it uses display: block, floats etc., but I am moving towards flex and grid in newer html pages to make it more mobile friendly but still I am constrained by default page though I could try to make that mobile friendly).  However, I am left with page url extensions, mobile unfriendly site.  Currently web.config is used for url redirection.

I thought of going fully with html/css/javascript if so how could I handle url redirection and  removal url extensions?    Or shall continue to use a mix of aspx and html pages as I currently have and update for  responsiveness and eliminate url extensions using friendly urls nuget package.  May be there is a better way.  Appreciate your thoughts and input. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, how are you constrained by the default.aspx page? You should be able to use HTML classes and tags on it like anything else and render it responsively like the html pages. ~.aspx pages are just pages of HTML that allow code blocks and form controls on them that get processed by the server into html and AJAX (if there's a corresponding code behind file and the certain form controls are used). I'm not sure how it would be any different to make it responsive than any of the html files you have as well.

Regarding routing, what's the motivation for wanting to drop WebForms routing and url redirection? You can get around it with Javascript if you want, but at that point you don't even need WebForms or a backend if you're also trying to get rid of the default.aspx page. Does the site only serve static content and doesn't need a database or server logic at all?

Comment: Thanks James. I didn't realize the WebForms routing (will explore and is great idea.  I wonder what's the benefit of this vs adding it the web.config file.  any advantage from SEO perspective?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, those asp.net pages and menus ARE bootstrap, and ARE responsive.

You seem to be under the impression that aspx pages and web forms are somehow LESS responsive then HTML pages or some other frame work.

That is NOT the case.

In other words some act of magic does not exist or occur by jumping to MVC pages, or HTML pages.

You get ZERO advantages.

Even for asp.net web forms, bootstrap “responsive” pages has been the default for more then 10 years now.

So, you see this as a web form page (aspx), and NOTE the menu bar:

[image]

Ok, lets make the page smaller. we get:

[image]

And if we go even smaller, then the menu bar colipases to the familiar "hamburger" like this:

[image]

And the same goes even for a standard say grid.

Say we drop in a grid like this:

[image]

Ok, lets shrink down to mobile - menu bar goes to hamburger, and we get this:

[image]

So, I am not convinced that simply going to HTML, or MVC pages will help much.

To get a nice responsive and re-sizing web page?

The aspx pages seem to work and do as good as job as most frameworks. And the efforts to get similar or even better results?

I don't see much difference. You might want to give a particular example, but aspx pages based on good old web forms seems to do as good as a job as most choices these days. Out of the box, the menu and pages are bootstrapped, and they are responsive.

It takes extra effort, and some talent to lay out such pages, and make them work well for any frame work if the same page is to be mobile friendly all the way up to say a large monitor on a desktop.

I open to adopting a newer framework works better, but those better results are that of the developer choosing to lay things out better - not that by just magic we drop the aspx page and you as a result get a better mobile experience.

Comment: Thanks Albert.  I attempted bootsstrap(explored the navbar and grid) I think your feedback helped me to understand the value of aspx. . Where I am not clear is,  how can I bring the SCSS and CSS files in the VS project -  should I create a new folder for e.g. under project ---> scss and add files there and what about scss mapping?  can I still be able to visually add the bootsrap grid or cards for e.g. similar to how we did with creating table element (each form has designer view that was very helpful).

Comment: bootstrap + boostrap.js for responsive pages  is the default and is included by default. Aspx pages HAVE to spit out standard 100% browser HTML, else they could not work. So aspx pages don't effect these choices for css etc. Listview, Gridview etc. render as HTML tables. You free to add css to them, but at least you don't have to write a loop to generate a silly table. That above grid was filled with 4 lines of c# code and no looping code. That's why we use aspx pages - tons of dirty work is done for you. I'm betting that bootstrap and css files already exist in that project.